# Xamarin Forms OnPlatform in Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have the following C# code:

```
var footer = new StackLayout()
            { BackgroundColor = Device.OnPlatform(Color.FromRgb(225, 240, 251), Color.FromRgb(225, 240, 251), Color.Black),
            };
```

How can I translate that into Xamarin Xaml, more importantly the Device Platform specifics for the FromRgb?

I have the following XAML so far... again, it's the FromRgb that's stumping me.

```
<StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
    <Color>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color"></OnPlatform>
    </Color>
</StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
```

UPDATE 14/02/2015

I've just tried the answer below and I have the following but it's not updating the background colour for either iOS or Windows Phone.  If I add the Background Color to the root StackLayout element it works...:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
      <Color>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
          <OnPlatform.WinPhone>#51C0D4</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
          <OnPlatform.iOS>#51C0D4</OnPlatform.iOS>
        </OnPlatform>
      </Color>
    </StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
    <Label Text=""></Label>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
      <Button Text="Login"></Button>
      <Button Text="Sign Up"></Button>
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. The default converter takes care of converting the color from either a named color (e.g. White, Red, etc.) or a hex color (e.g.: #FF0000).

```
<StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>#FF0000</OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android>#00FF00</OnPlatform.Android>
    </OnPlatform>
</StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
```

Comment: Wups! My bad. I copied your code for my answer, and it has a syntax error. Do not include that <Color> element; just have the OnPlatform element as a child of BackgroundColor (edited answer as well).

Comment: Oh, and I'm digging the idea for a baby diary app. Wish I'd had one for my kids...

Comment: Thanks. Ah, I should have tried that, I didn't realise!  I actually started writing my Page's in code.  Am I right in saying that you don't get a Visual Designer in VS for Xamarin Xaml pages?  If not, I don't see any advantage writing the Page in xaml over code.  Oops, I didn't mean to leave the application's name in there... taken out now.  Xamarin is a massive learning curve... just got my navigation working last night (after reading up) using Messaging...

Comment: I personally prefer XAML over code; it's easier to visualize hierarchies, and it also acts as a way to remind the developer that "this is UI; no logic allowed."

Comment: That's a good point, however, MVVM helps you do that too.  I'm currently using Mvvm Light!  Really liking it so far.  As I say this is all new to me!

Comment: You know what, I might change back to Xaml... I've only written two pages so far.

Comment: Is there a way of binding the value for OnPlatform rather than hard coding it? <OnPlatform.iOS><Binding {StaticResource BackgroundColorChoice}/></OnPlatform.iOS>

Comment: @ClintStLaurent Yes, create a property BackgroundColorChoice in code and use the code provided in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Newer version syntax of OnPlatform is slightly different

In Xaml:

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="SwitchOnColor"  x:TypeArguments="Color" >
                <On Platform="iOS|Android" >#0000FF</On>
                <On Platform="UWP">#FF0000</On>
            </OnPlatform>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

In code:

```
 switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
 {
     case "iOS":
     break;
     case "Android":
     break;
     case "UWP":
     break;
     default:
     break;
 }
```

Comment: Here is a great article about this: https://montemagno.com/important-onplatform-changes-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also:

```
<ContentView>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
            <On Platform="iOS">
                <Label Text="iOS" />
            </On>
            <On Platform="Android">
                <Label Text="Android" />
            </On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentView>
```